# How to get Slack User Token for Slack App to Post Message on User Behalf

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to make a Slack App that can send messages on user behalf (similar to Giphy, which apparently is different than regular Slack Apps).

In order to send messages as users (not just impersonating using chat:write.customized), I need the user's User Token.

When you install the app, it automatically generates a user token for the installer account, but I need a token for every user that wants to use the app.

The Slack API says "User tokens represent workspace members. They are issued for the user who installed the app and for **users who authenticate the app**."

How can I get users to authenticate the app and get a token for them? Is that possible?

Thank you!

I've tried searching around, but haven't been able to find much information on this yet. Others have said that you need to use the Slack App oauth page to get tokens, but I'm still not sure how users can "authenticate the app".

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Was wondering the exact same thing.

Comment: @Andy I was able to get it to work! You need to send the user's token as the token for any API calls (like postMessage and such). You'd need to get authorization from the user to use their token which requires a web server to catch the token. At least, that's how I got it to work.